# Padding on parent element not keeping child element inside

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where I have a parent div (`section__info__wrap`) with position relative which I have applied padding on all 4 sides, the child element is an absolute div (`section__info`) but the padding only seems to be applying correctly on the left hand side. I have added a fiddle below with all my mark up to show whats happening.

If i remove the div (`section__info__wrap`) and apply the padding directly to the absolute positioned element (`section__info`) it works fine.

I know its no doubt something simple but i just cant work out whats going on.

https://jsfiddle.net/1sp30h70/2/

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.section__inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.section__info__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 5rem;
}

.section__info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13%;
  //padding: 0 10rem;
}

.section__text {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.intro__img {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-med-6 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.secondary__heading {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #000000;
}

.secondary__heading::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #000000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="section intro">
  <div class="section__inner">
    <div class="col-med-6 no-padding">
      <div class="intro__img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-med-6 no-padding">
      <div class="section__info__wrap">
        <div class="section__info">
          <h3 class="secondary__heading">Im a heading</h3>
          <p class="section__text">This is test text, This is test text,This is test text,This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text, This is test text.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Rufus did my suggested solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Rufus Since you are using `position:relative` for `section__info__wrap` class, you also need to use float property for padding to work properly.

check this https://jsfiddle.net/1sp30h70/4/.

i add `float:left;` to section__info__wrap class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, i just find it strange that a floated element would allow this to work.